# Input number is odd or even - Message not displaying

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning Javascript & i cant figure out why this code wont work, the submit button wont display any results.
I want to try the task in my way & not in any of the ways listed online as we havent learnt how to do that yet.
I think this is a very efficient method which does not include any prompts or alerts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Task 2</title>
<style>
h1 {font-family:serif; font-size:48px; color:#ff00ff; text-align:center}
h2 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:36px; color:#0000ff; text-align:center}
h3 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#00ffff; text-align: center}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div align="center">

<h1 id="type1">Checking whether a number is odd or even</h1>
<h3 id="type3"></h3>

</div>

<h2>Enter number</h2>
<form id="numtype" action="/action_page.php" style="font-size: 24px">

    <input id="ooe" type="number" name="num" style="font-size: 24px" placeholder="Enter number">  <br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" style="font-size: 24px">

<script>

    function myFunction() {
        
        var num=document.getElementById('ooe').value

        if ( num % 2 == 0 )
        document.getElementById('type2')("Entered number is even");
     else
        document.getElementById('type2')("Entered number is odd");
        
        }

</script>
<h2 id="type2"></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use this `document.getElementById('type2').text = 'Entered number is odd'` instead

Comment: `document.getElementById()` not returns `function`

Comment: Learn to use the console: it gives an error message that would have helped you identify which line in your code is producing an error and what it is. Press F12 to open the console in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.textContent` to display the results. You are not displaying any message on your submit click event.

You can read more about `.textContent` on [JS MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Run snippet below to see in it working.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var num = document.getElementById('ooe').value

  if (num % 2 == 0)
    document.getElementById('type2').textContent = "Entered number is even";
  else
    document.getElementById('type2').textContent = "Entered number is odd";

}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #ff00ff;
  text-align: center
}

h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #0000ff;
  text-align: center
}

h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #00ffff;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Basic Task 2</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div align="center">

    <h1 id="type1">Checking whether a number is odd or even</h1>
    <h3 id="type3"></h3>

  </div>

  <h2>Enter number</h2>
  <form id="numtype" action="" style="font-size: 24px">

    <input id="ooe" type="number" name="num" style="font-size: 24px" placeholder="Enter number"> <br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" style="font-size: 24px">
 <h2 id="type2"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `document.getElementById('type2')("Entered number is even");` you need to use `.textContent`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Basic Task 2</title>
<style>
h1 {font-family:serif; font-size:48px; color:#ff00ff; text-align:center}
h2 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:36px; color:#0000ff; text-align:center}
h3 {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:24px; color:#00ffff; text-align: center}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div align="center">

<h1 id="type1">Checking whether a number is odd or even</h1>
<h3 id="type3"></h3>

</div>

<h2>Enter number</h2>
<form id="numtype" action="/action_page.php" style="font-size: 24px">

    <input id="ooe" type="number" name="num" style="font-size: 24px" placeholder="Enter number">  <br><br>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" style="font-size: 24px">

<script>

    function myFunction() {
        
        var num = document.getElementById('ooe').value

        if ( num % 2 == 0 )
        document.getElementById('type2').textContent = "Entered number is even" ;
     else
        document.getElementById('type2').textContent = "Entered number is odd";
        
        }

</script>

<h2 id="type2"></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its not recemended to use innerHTML. Read MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process.